# MacBook Pro not responding to power button

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro, osx-mavericks

My Mac wont start up even with full battery and charger plugged in... There is no sound, no screen or any disk movement.

The same thing also happened a few weeks back and when I took it to the repair guy; he fixed it in a matter of minutes.

He held down the power button for 10 seconds, removed the charger and did *something* else and the system started working but I don't exactly remember what he did.

**Can anyone tell me what those magic steps are?**

I am currently out of town and can’t take it there again.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try: "Press the (left) Shift-Control-Option key combination along with the power button once" to reset the system management controller.